# JShowOff: How to make the thumbnail expand horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jshowoff

I'm using jshowoff thumbFeatures and found it nice. But as long as I add images, the thumbnails flooded and goes in the bottom of the box.

I want it to be like this [click here....](http://jsfiddle.net/vKUaa/34/)

I found the thumbnail box is in this line of jshowoff.css `.thumbFeatures p.jshowoff-slidelinks`

I've tried every code that the link above had given just to change it but nothing happens

This is the image of my work: [click me....](http://i57.tinypic.com/2wfideb.png)

if you noticed, one other image is in the bottom.

Any idea is accepted. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: the same problem here.....